# Why does application of `sequence` on List of Lists lead to computation of its Cartesian Product?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, cartesian-product

My question is about the `sequence` function in `Prelude`, the signature of which is as follows:

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

I understand how this function works for `List` of `Maybe`s. For example, applying `sequence` on `[Just 3, Just 9]` gives `Just [3, 9]`.

I noticed that applying `sequence` on `List` of `List`s gives its Cartesian Product. Can someone please help me understand how/why this happens?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This works because using lists as monads in Haskell makes them model indeterminism. Consider:

```
sequence [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

By definition this is the same as:

```
do x <- [1,2]
   y <- [3,4]
   return [x,y]
```

Just read it as "First a choice between 1 and 2, then a choice between 3 and 4". The list monad will now accumulate **all** possible outcomes - hence the answer `[[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]`.

(for an even more obfuscated example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634962/where-can-i-learn-advanced-haskell/4639663))

Comment: BTW, the last term is exactly the same as the respective list-comprehension-expression [[x,y] | x <- [1,2], y <-[3,4]] -- this perhaps makes it clearer that it yield the Cartesian Product.

Answer (score 23):

`sequence` acts as if it were defined like this.

```
sequence [] = return []
sequence (m:ms) = do
    x <- m
    xs <- sequence ms
    return (x:xs)
```

(Or `sequence = foldr (liftM2 (:)) (return [])` but anyhow…)

Just think about what happens when applied to a list of lists.

```
sequence [] = [[]]
sequence (list : lists) =
    [ x : xs
    | x <- list
    , xs <- sequence lists
    ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to explain, why the application of sequence to a list of lists is so different from the application of sequence to a list of Maybe-values:

When you apply `sequence` to a list of lists, then the type of sequence is specialized from

```
sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
```

to (with the type constructor m set to [])

```
sequence :: [[] a] -> [] [a]
```

(which is the same as `sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`)

internally, sequence uses (>>=) -- i.e. the monadic bind function. For lists this bind function is implemented completly different than for m set to Maybe!

Comment: "is so different from" --> "is *not* so different from" ?