# cross product of arbitrary number of lists in scala

Tags: scala

I have a list of lists in Scala as follows.

```
val inputList:List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 9))
```

I want a list of cross products of all the sub-lists.

```
val desiredOutput: List[List[Int]] = List( 
        List(1, 3, 1), List(1, 3, 9),
        List(1, 4, 1), List(1, 4, 9),
        List(1, 5, 1), List(1, 5, 9),
        List(2, 3, 1), List(2, 3, 9),
        List(2, 4, 1), List(2, 4, 9),
        List(2, 5, 1), List(2, 5, 9))
```

The number of elements in inputList as well as the sublist are not fixed. What is the Scala way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `scalaz`, this may be a suitable case for `Applicative Builder`:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def desiredOutput(input: List[List[Int]]) = 
  input.foldLeft(List(List.empty[Int]))((l, r) => (l |@| r)(_ :+ _))

desiredOutput(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 9)))
```

I am not very familiar with scalaz myself, and I expect it has some more powerful magic to do this.

**Edit**

As Travis Brown suggest, we just write

```
def desiredOutput(input: List[List[Int]]) = input.sequence
```

And I find the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299295/why-does-application-of-sequence-on-list-of-lists-lead-to-computation-of-its-c) very helpful for understanding what `sequence` does.

Comment: thanks. looks elegant..but scary at the same time! will learn scalaz after I master basic Scala.

Comment: You're right about more powerful magic: this is in fact just sequencing the top-level list, so you can write `input.sequence` here.

Comment: This is very very cool ... like OMG scala & scalaz so clearly pwns every other language in the universe.  I would love to see a similar thing done LAZILY!!! I.e. for `Iterator[Iterator[T]]` that returns `Iterator[Iterator[T]]`

Comment: FYI, if you want to terse it up a bit you can do: `(List(List.empty[Int]) /: input)(_ |@| _ |> (_(_ :+ _)))` ... in fact I kinda wish `sequence` didn't exist just so I would have an excuse to use such code.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method that works using recursion. However it is not tail recursive so beware of stackoverflows. However it can be transformed to a tail recursive function by using an auxiliary function.

```
def getProduct(input:List[List[Int]]):List[List[Int]] = input match{
  case Nil => Nil // just in case you input an empty list
  case head::Nil => head.map(_::Nil) 
  case head::tail => for(elem<- head; sub <- getProduct(tail)) yield elem::sub
}
```

Test:

```
scala> getProduct(inputList)
res32: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 3, 1), List(1, 3, 9), List(1, 4, 1), List(1, 4, 9), List(1, 5, 1), List(1, 5, 9), List(2, 3, 1), List(2, 3, 9), List(2, 4, 1), List(2, 4, 9), List(2, 5, 1), List(2, 5, 9))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a bit of functional programming:

```
def cross[T](inputs: List[List[T]]) : List[List[T]] = 
    inputs.foldRight(List[List[T]](Nil))((el, rest) => el.flatMap(p => rest.map(p :: _)))
```

Much fun finding out how that works. :-)

Comment: this is insane!

Comment: @botkop Not really. Scala is for professional programmers that are used to it, of course. If you know Scala and functional programming decently well, this is a very clear and understandable way to describe the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, I arrived at this solution.

```
val inputList: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4, 5), List(1, 9))
val zss: List[List[Int]] = List(List())
def fun(xs: List[Int], zss: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
    for {
        x <- xs
        zs <- zss
    } yield {
        x :: zs
    }
}
val crossProd: List[List[Int]] = inputList.foldRight(zss)(fun _)
println(crossProd)
```