# Python - Algorithm to generate all possible arrays of ones and zeros of a given length

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

My goal is to come up with an array of all possible bit combinations of length n. For example, if n = 3, the target answer set should look like

```
000,
001,
010,
100,
011,
101,
110,
111
```

I've found the [algorithmic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633584/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-arrays-of-ones-and-zeros-of-a-given-length), by I have completely no experience in iterators and C++ in general. Could someone give a hint how to rewrite the next function in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> result = ["".join(item) for item in itertools.product("01", repeat=3)]
>>> print result
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

Answer (score 2):

Without itertools: print the numbers from `0` to `2 ** n` in base 2 and pad them with zeros:

```
for i in range(2 ** n):
    print('{0:b}'.format(i).rjust(n, '0'))
```

Note that this leads to a much simpler solution in any language. All you need is a function to convert from base ten to base two. Then, for each number from `0` to `2 ** n`, you convert it to base 2 and print or store the conversion.

To convert `x` to base two, divide it by `2` until it reaches `0` and keep track of the remainders. The list of remainders, in reverse order, is `x` in base 2:

```
x = 13
13 / 2 = 6 remainder 1
 6 / 2 = 3 remainder 0
 3 / 2 = 1 remainder 1
 1 / 2 = 0 remainder 1

=> 13 in base 2 = 1101
```

Comment: Alternatively, just a list comprehension: ` ['{0:b}'.format(i).rjust(n, '0') for i in range(2 ** n)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

#Possible characters
n = [0, 1]
#Asking required length
l = int(input("length: "))
#Putting all possibilities in list
r = list(itertools.product(n, repeat=l))

print(r)
```

Python always has a few handy libraries or functions to make complex things easy, and to make long taking work short.

In `itertools.product()` your first parameter should be an array of the characters of which you want all possibilities, and the second after the repeat-keyword is the length of the results.